# Salesforce lightning component controller apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Having some issues creating a test class for controller. It's assisting a lightning component that loads record types for the cases object instead of hardcoding it. I bet I'm over thinking it. Would love some helpful insight on how to test for this.

```
public class recordtypeController {
public static Map<Id, String> recordtypemap {get;set;}

@AuraEnabled        
public static List<String> fetchRecordTypeValues(){
    List<Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordtypes = 
Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos();    
    recordtypemap = new Map<Id, String>();
    for(RecordTypeInfo rt : recordtypes){
        if(rt.getName() != 'Master')
        recordtypemap.put(rt.getRecordTypeId(), rt.getName());
    }        
    return recordtypemap.values();
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Id getRecTypeId(String recordTypeLabel){
    Id recid = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(recordTypeLabel).getRecordTypeId();        
    return recid;
 }      
}
```

Test Class:

```
 @isTest
 public class recordtypeControllerTest {


private static testmethod void testFetchRecordTypes() {
    List<String> values = recordtypeController.fetchRecordTypeValues();
}

private static testmethod void testgetRecordTypeId() {
    string recordTypeLabel = 'Customer Service';
    ID testId = recordtypeController.getRecTypeId(recordTypeLabel);
   } 
 }
```

Comment: can you post your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: seems you do not need to create any records to test your code. It is just describe information. call methods and assert vales. done

Comment: Thank you Eric. I never had to write a test class for this type of controller before. However one issue is that I'm passing in 'recordTypeLabel' from the lightning component client controller. I don't see any documentation on how to test the method without this variable. Getting errors.

Comment: It's just a string. Do a describe, get a record type name, pass that in and assert the right id comes back

Comment: Updated my existing code. Have 90% coverage but have a Nullpointer exception which I think I know why. And have a Stack Trace which I believe to be due to a logic error in my test class.

Comment: Figured it out. I'll update my with the test class 100% coverage and assertion passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@isTest
public class recordtypeControllerTest {


static testmethod void testFetchRecordTypes() {
    List<String> values = recordtypeController.fetchRecordTypeValues();
  }

 static testmethod void testgetRecordTypeId() {
    String recordTypeLabel = 'Customer Service';
    ID testId = recordtypeController.getRecTypeId(recordTypeLabel);
    System.assert(testId != null);
  }

}
```